# What is platform() in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone explain what `platform()` does in SQL server 2008?

Comment: Where and in what context did you discover `platform()` ?

Comment: I copied some text from some paragraph and paste in ssms for my reference and accidentally I have found platform in built-in function color. Then i have searched for long and I can't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9ca2ac61-07da-43ba-9f8c-6f81fdac5e25/platform-function?forum=sqldatabaseengine) in October 2017 `PLATFORM()` *is still in development* whether or not that is still the case I could not find anything about it in a quick google search.

It appears that `PLATFORM()` is similar to `@@VERSION` as a quote from Erland on the link above

> When I tested it in my Azure database (Basic
>   edition) it return 1029, which is the same value it returns on any
>   64-bit instance I've tried. On my SQL 2000 and SQL7 instances which
>   are 32-bit and runs 32-bit operating systems (I think) on 64-bit
>   virtual hardware, it returns 1025. The function is not available in
>   SQL 6.5.
>
> The value is obviously a bit mask of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDB stored procedures , it is used to find out what SKU of Windows is the server using :

```
IF ((PLATFORM() & 0x1) = 0x1) -- NT

IF ((PLATFORM() & 0x2) = 0x2) -- Win9x

/* check that local server is not running a desktop SKU */
if( PLATFORM() & 0x100 = 0x100 ) -- Win9x, Office, or MSDE
```

Please note that this seems to be an undocumented internal MS function and is therefore not recommended to be used in User Code