# In SQL Server 2019, what does the function Platform() do?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2019, the word **platform** is colored magenta in SSMS.

There is no documentation of this function anywhere, and ChatGPT and Gemini are clueless about this as well. However - it must be something.

When I execute "print Platform();" I get an integer return value of 1029.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50848211/53341

Comment: Thank you. That exactly answers my question.